# Append NSData to a file in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, append, nsdata

I'm attempting to download a large file on the iPhone and save it to disk as it is downloaded.

Ideally, in:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {

}
```

I want to append 'data' to a file on disk.

I've checked out the NSData documentation. There are functions to write to a file, but I can't see anything to append to an existing file.

Does anyone know how I can append this data? Any help much appreciated!
Nick.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use a combination of `-writeData:` and `-seekToEndOfFile` methods from `NSFileHandle` class for writing `NSData` to the end of a file.

Comment: Genius. I swear I looked over the NSFileHandle documentation a few times before writing this post! Must have completely missed these functions!
N

Comment: Why not to use NSMutableData? It has appendData: method!

Comment: NSMutableData works in RAM -- downloading a file of any real size will take up your resources.

Comment: Yup,Vineel is right.Writing to a file using NSData is convenient but don't use it to write too big a file, or you'll get crashed.

Comment: And finally check this answer for sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106584/appending-to-the-end-of-a-file-with-nsmutablestring

Answer (score -1):

There's a Apple sample app that downloads to a file, using NSOutputStream to write to the file. Look in file "GetController.h" of the sample app called "SimpleURLConnections".

Here's a direct URL -- although I don't think it'll work if you're not logged into to developer.apple.com.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer.