# How to concatenate when printing to txt file?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to call a method that prints to a txt file. But then when I call the method again it will just overwrite what was in the text file with my new text. I want to file to just keep adding what is printed.

```
-(void) print:(NSString *)name
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/here/file.txt"];
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithFormat"@"%@\n", name];
[fileContent writeToURL:url atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```

When I call this method I am calling it by doing:

```
[name print: person1.name];
[name print: person2.name];
```

Everytime I try to print the next name it just replaces the name in the text file. I am unsure how to concantenate and continue adding the names?

Thank you

I have tried this:

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"/here/file.txt"];
NSString *textToWrite = @"hello";
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:[textToWrite dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandle closeFile];
```

Nothing is printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:aPath];
if (!fileHandle){
    NSLog(@"Error: File does not exist!");
} else {
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData:[textToWrite dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fileHandle closeFile];
}
```

Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11106678/2115477

Comment: Updated my first post.

Comment: Note that if you use NSFileHandle, you must make sure that the file exists before hand. fileHandleForWritingAtPath will return nil if no file exists at the path. See the NSFileHandle class reference.  
Also from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11106678/2115477

You could also use the second approach:
`NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
contents = [contents stringByAppendingString:textToWrite];
[contents writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES encoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&err];`

Comment: File does exist in that exact location.

Comment: please debug and look if fileHandle is `nil` after `fileHandleWritingAtPath`. If it's `nil` there's no file to write at that path: [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilehandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFileHandle/fileHandleForWritingAtPath:)

Comment: I dont know how to do that

Comment: i added a if-else statement to my answer.

Comment: I am new to this. i don't know what you are talking about. I know what a if else statement is but I don't know how to do what your wanting. The file IS there. I had it working with the exact same file directory but it just wasn't appending. Now i changed it to the above fileHandle method and its not working. I right click on the file.txt and view file information to copy the exact directory path.

Comment: Just tried it and nothing is printing to the console.

Comment: I got it to work. Some reason my program was being paused so I deactivated breakpoints and now it is working. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is better (I tried to integrate your solution)

```
-(void) print:(NSString *)name
{
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file.txt" 
                                                     ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:NULL];
    NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithFormat"%@\n%@", content, name];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [fileContent writeToURL:url atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```

even though I guess there could be more efficient ways.