# Read a number, then print the integers from 1 to the number to a file

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"E:/NumsToIntFile" contents:nil attributes:nil];

    int num = 0;
    int x = 1;

    printf("\nEnter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while(num >= x)
    {
       NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ", x];
       [str writeToFile:"E:/NumsToIntFile" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
       x++;
    }

    NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"E:/NumsToIntFile"];
    NSLog(@"%@",contents);
    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

What exactly is wrong with this code? Something in line 17 (`[str writeToFile:"E:/NumsToIntFile" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];`) creates an error and I don't know how to fix it.

NOTE: This is via Notepad++ on Windows 7

Comment: main.m: In function 'main': main.m:17:5: warning passing arguement 1 of 'writeToFile:atomatically:encoding:error:' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an at symbol `@` in front of the `"E:/NumsToIntFile"` argument on line 17.

Comment: It works but there's one more error: main.m:17:5: warning: passing arguement 4 of 'writeToFile:atomatically:encoding:error:' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]    main.m:17:5: note: expected 'struct NSError **' but arguement is of type 'id'

Comment: Declare an NSError pointer like this:  `NSError *error;`   and pass its address as the 4th argument:  `[str writeToFile:@"E:/NumsToIntFile" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];`

Comment: `writeToFile:...` does not append to a file.  To append, use `NSFileHandle`.  See [Appending to the end of a file with nsmutablestring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106584/appending-to-the-end-of-a-file-with-nsmutablestring).